# How to get angle of rotation in Y axis for an Offset

Tags: graphics, geometry, trigonometry, android-graphics

I am trying to get the angle of rotation for an offset rotated in the Y-axis. Say When an offset(400, 0, 0) is rotated in Y-axis, I need to find the right angle so that the new offset x intersect with pre-known x-axis value (in my case it is 350)
[image]

Comment: Question is not clear. Please make better description, perhaps with a picture.

Comment: Hi, @MBo I have edited the question and attached a picture. take a look at it

Comment: Why are the vectors marked with 2 numbers each, rather than 3? Did you omit the Z coord? Is Y always zero?

Comment: In my case, Y is always zero, but it can be variable too. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @MBo my question was wrong all along. Kindly take a look at it now. And sorry for the previous half baked question

Comment: If you know `x2=350` (is it true?), but don't know z2 (needed only for angle sign refinement), then @HolyBlackCat answer with `acos` was what you need.

Comment: I have the x axis value as 350 before the rotation, after rotation it will vary right so x2  is unknown right? @MBo

Comment: So I don't understand your question. What is 400 ? You cannot solve right-angle triangle having the only side.

Answer (score 0):

Let initial coordinates were `(x0, z0)`, new coordinates are `(x1, z1)`. Using formulas for rotation about axis OY by (unknown yet) angle `fi`

```
x1 = x0 * cos(fi) - z0 * sin(fi)
z1 = x0 * sin(fi) + z0 * cos(fi)
```

We can find (solving this system of linear equations)  that

```
sin(fi) = (z1 * x0 - z0 * x1) / (x0*x0 + z0*z0)
cos(fi) = (x1 * x0 + z0 * z1) / (x0*x0 + z0*z0)
```

and get rotation angle

```
fi = math.atan2(z1 * x0 - z0 * x1, x1 * x0 + z0 * z1)
```